Fetch twice recursively to do speed rate calculations with response from server
My server (Python - Django) response is a JSON object containig rx and tx expressed in bytes from a networking router, which then I need to show to the user as Download speed in Mbps and Upload speed in Mbps whether it's in a Chart or a continuosly updating div until the user closes the modal where he sees the info. So the problem is I need to request two times for data to then calculate RX/TX rates and then keep requesting and calculating tx/rx speed rates.
Right now I'm achieving what I expected at my skill level but I certainly know its not the best way, I need your help to do it rigth and as efficient as possible.
Any help would be great, thanks
This is my server response expressed in bytes, I need to request 2 times so I can calculate differences:
{
    "rx": "14986885547",
    "tx": "228270858519"
}

This is what I have:
const custId = document.getElementById('customerId')

    var bytesArr = [];
    var timeout = null;
    var traffic = (function getTraffic() {
        let url = '/customer_detail/traffic/';
        fetch(url+custId.innerText, { method: 'GET' })
        .then(Result => Result.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            update_data(data);
        })
        .catch(errorMsg => { console.log(errorMsg); });
        return getTraffic;
    })();
    
    function update_data(data){
        if (bytesArr.length<2){
            let arrlenght = bytesArr.push(data);
        }else{
            bytesArr.shift();
        }
        calcRates(bytesArr);
    }

    function calcRates(array){
        let startBytesIn, startBytesOut, endBytesIn, endBytesOut, txBytesPerSecond, rxBytesPerSecond = null;
        if(array.length==2){
            for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if(i==0){
                    startBytesIn = array[i].rx;
                    startBytesOut = array[i].tx;
                }else if(i==1){
                    endBytesIn = array[i].rx;
                    endBytesOut = array[i].tx;
                }
            }
            txBytesPerSecond = (endBytesOut-startBytesOut)
            rxBytesPerSecond = (endBytesIn-startBytesIn)
            console.log('Down Speed Mbps ',(txBytesPerSecond/125000).toFixed(2));
            console.log('Up Speed Mbps ',(rxBytesPerSecond/125000).toFixed(2));
        }else{
            txBytesPerSecond = txBytesPerSecond;
            rxBytesPerSecond = rxBytesPerSecond;
        }    
        timeout = setTimeout(traffic, 1000);
    }

and right now I'm clearing the timeout when clicking a button.
